# Split big text string into small ones

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I'm reading text file into one string and then spliting the whole file into array of strings with this code:

```
string[] split_text = Regex.Split(whole_text, @"\W+");
```

But when I do that every word is alone on one index and I don't want that.

I want biger string on one index let say about 10 words on one index in array and then 10 words on second index and so on.

So if I read file of 90 words I want to have size of array 9 and on every index 10 words.

Comment: is the all `90` words present on a single line?

Comment: did you try `"\W{10}"`?

Comment: you could try matching instead of splitting. http://ideone.com/bbzhFV

Comment: I just tryed and does not word. Thanks @Khanh TO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Batch`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28) method:

```
string[] split_text = Regex.Split(whole_text, @"\W+")
              .Batch(10)
              .Select(x => string.Concat(x))
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Batch'. I get this error do I have to include something? @Selman22

Comment: yes you need to download MoreLINQ and add a reference it.

Comment: I installed MoreLINQ using this link: [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable/) and then I included Linq using this code `Using System.Linq` and I still can't use `.Batch` @Selman22

Answer (score 1):

ok there is full sollution :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        string text = "Now im checking first ten chars from sentence and some random chars : asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd";
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i = i + 10)
            {
                string res = text.Substring(i,10);
                result.Add(res);
                Console.WriteLine(res);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend use `List<string>` instead of array of strings.